# The class with [Ljava.util.Date; and name of [Ljava.util.Date; is not trusted

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-databind

I am using spring batch version as 4.2.4.RELEASE and jackson data bind version as 2.10.2.

I am using custom class which will hold my batch parameters. It is inserting json in BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT data as follow.

```json
{
  "@class": "java.util.HashMap",
  "stepName": "2",
  "JobDetails": {
  "@class": "com.test.hk.framework.JobDetails",
  "host": "ABCDE",
  "Dates1": ["[Ljava.util.Date;", [
    ["java.sql.Date", 1610649000000],
    ["java.sql.Date", 1610562600000],
    ["java.sql.Date", 1610735400000]
  ]],
  "Date2": ["java.sql.Date", "2021-01-14T18:30:00.000"],
  "subTaskInfo": {
    "@class": "java.util.HashMap",
    "1": {
      "@class": "com.test.hk.framework.ei.SubTaskModel",
      "eiTaskSeq": "2",
      "eiSubTaskSeq": "1",
      "criticaFlag": "Y"
    },
    "2": {
      "@class": "com.test.hk.framework.ei.SubTaskModel",
      "eiTaskSeq": "2",
      "eiSubTaskSeq": "2",
      "criticaFlag": "Y"
    },
    "3": {
      "@class": "com.test.hk.framework.ei.SubTaskModel",
      "eiTaskSeq": "2",
      "eiSubTaskSeq": "3",
      "criticaFlag": "Y"
    },
    "4": {
      "@class": "com.test.hk.framework.ei.SubTaskModel",
      "eiTaskSeq": "2",
      "eiSubTaskSeq": "4",
      "criticaFlag": "Y"
    },
    "5": {
      "@class": "com.test.hk.framework.ei.SubTaskModel",
      "eiTaskSeq": "2",
      "eiSubTaskSeq": "5",
      "criticaFlag": "Y"
    }
  },
  "extraInfo": null,
  "eventCode": 0,
  "taskId": null,
  "instanceId": null,
  "jobStatus": null,
  "module": "Movie",
  "mEB1Flg": "",
  "mEB2odPrg": "",
  "eKey": "",
  "status": false,
  "flgSuccessful": false,
  "flgSysDateChg": false
  }
}
```

In above json Dates1 and Date2 are util date, however it is storing as sql, while de serializing it is giving following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class with [Ljava.util.Date; and name of [Ljava.util.Date; is not trusted. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or a custom ObjectMapper. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing.
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer$TrustedTypeIdResolver.typeFromId(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:329) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:156) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:97) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromArray(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserializeWithType(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:227) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserializeWithType(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:21) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:138) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:194) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:130) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:97) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:193) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:712) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:529) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:2.10.2]
```

java code`
@Component
public class JobDetails implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6522158878630126214L;
private String host = "";
private Date[] date1;
private boolean mFlgSysDateChg;
private boolean mFlgSuccessful;
private boolean mStatus;
private java.util.Date date2;
private Map<String, SubTaskModel> subTaskInfo;
private Map<String, Object> extraInfo;
private int eventCode;
private String taskId;
private String instanceId;
private String jobStatus;
private String module;
private String mEB2Flg = "";
private String mEB1Prg = "";
private String eKey = "";
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what type of Date object you're using where and whether there is conversion between dateformats happening here, but with reference to [this PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/3787), you may wish to upgrade to spring-batch 4.3.x and make use of the added ability to extend the list of classes which are considered safe/trusted for deserialisation.

You should also prefer to use the java.time.* package over java.util.Date. See [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) for a good overview of why.

Comment: When I use spring-batch version as 4.2.0 it works fine, however issue comes when I upgraded it to 4.2.4 version. I have pasted my pojo above where date fields are util date. So spring batch converts this pojo and puts in the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table where date fields are converted in above format. I did upgrade this to 4.3.0 version as well but issue remain the same.

Comment: Having upgraded, I imagine you then need to extend the list of classes considered safe for deserialisation.